# Laravel Records Relationship issue

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have one to many relationship between `Applicant` and `pendingJob`, Where my Applicant model have `cnic` **primary key**, Where `pendingJob` have `applicant_id` and pointing it to `Applicant` model cnic column as foreign key.

**Applicant model :**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'cnic';

public function pending_jobs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\PendingJobs', 'applicant_id');
}
```

**PendingJob model :**

```
public function applicant() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Applicant', 'applicant_id');
}
```

I am inserting record in Applicant like :

```
$req = new \App\Applicant;
$req->full_name = $request->get('full_name');
$req->cnic = $request->get('cnic');
$req->mobile_number = $request->get('mobile_number');
$req->save();
```

Then record in `PendingJob` :

```
$reqr = new \App\PendingJob;
$reqr->applicant_id = $request->get('cnic');
$reqr->job_type = 'residence';
$reqr->status = 'pending';
$reqr->save();
```

The record saves and `cnic` which is the `primary key` of the `Applicant` and the `Pendingjob`'s `applicant_id` which is pointing to the `Applicant`'s `cnic` comes the same.

**But**

**The relationship does not loads, Manual record insertion from phpmydamin works fine.**

Comment: can you share your column names of Applicant and pendingJob tables?

Comment: Post your migrations. And please explain the part "Relationship does not load"

Answer (score 1):

The workflow should be this:

```
$reqr = new \App\PendingJob;
$reqr->job_type = 'residence';
$reqr->status = 'pending';

$req = new \App\Applicant;
$req->full_name = $request->get('full_name');
$req->cnic = $request->get('cnic');
$req->mobile_number = $request->get('mobile_number');

$reqr->applicant()->associate($req);

$reqr->save();
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Also, I'm noticing that your primary key for the applicant is `cnic` so your relationship should specify the `local_key` according to the Laravel documentation:

`App\Application`

```
public function pending_jobs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\PendingJobs', 'applicant_id', 'cnic');
}
```

`App\PendingJob`

```
public function applicant() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Applicant', 'applicant_id', 'id');
}
```